# mysql trigger information from a one to many relation insert and update triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have 3 tables: a,b and c. table a is related with table b with a one to many relaion and table c is the table that get the triggered infromation from the 2 other tables.

```
 table a
 ------------------
  id     |    name
   1     |    Juan 
   2     |    Pete
   3     |    David

 table b
 ----------------------
  id  |  name   | table_a_id
   1  |  Dog    |     1
   2  |  Cat    |     2
```

Table C gets the information from Table A with a "**after insert on A
for each row insert into C** "also gets information From table B with a "**after insert on B for each row update C**".

```
 table c
----------------------
id | name a | name b | table_a_id |table_b_id
 1 |  juan  |   Dog  |      1     |      1
 2 |  Pete  |   Cat  |      2     |      2
```

The problem occurs when Pete wants to have Cat and Dog at the same time because it will just update Pete's information. What i want is a way in which i can have a new row with all the information.

```
      table c
     -------------------------------------------
    id | name a | name b | table_a_id |table_b_id
     1 |  juan  |   Dog  |      1     |      1
     2 |  Pete  |   Cat  |      2     |      2
---->3 |  Pete  |   Dog  |      2     |      1
```

This 3rd row from table C wont be created it will just update row 2 from table C.

Comment: It does not appear sensible to insert from table a to table c.I suggest a  better approach would be to have a foreign key on tablea to table a based on table a id and have an insert trigger on tableb to table c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of having a physical copy of `table c`, you should create a "virtual table", or a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/views.html).

For example:

```
CREATE VIEW table_c AS (
    SELECT
    t1.id AS a_id,
    t1.`name` AS a_name,
    t2.id AS b_id,
    t2.`name` AS b_name
    FROM table_a t1
    LEFT JOIN table_b t2
    ON (t2.table_a_id = t1.id)
)
```

Now you can fetch rows from this "table" like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_c
```

Comment: thanks Jane! this might work, but if new information is in t1 and t2 it will show that information?

Comment: @cirlord yes.  It should show all rows that your example `table_c` shows.  If you are having problems setting it up update your code with what you tried and I can walk you through it.